# Why do the integral and the partial sum agree for small $a$ and $m$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals, divergent-series, fake-proofs

Consider the following naive manipulations:

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{1+ax}\:dx & = \int_0^\infty e^{-x}\frac{1}{1-(-ax)}\:dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-x} \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-ax)^n \right) \: dx\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-a)^n \int_0^\infty e^{-x}  x^n \: dx\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty n! (-a)^n \\
\end{align}

These are wrong, of course, since the integral we started with exists yet the partial sum $$\sum_{n=0}^m n! (-a)^n$$ is divergent. Yet for small $a$ and $m$ the approximation is quite accurate. Why does it "work" for small $a$ and $m$?

Comment: This is an asymptotic expansion. Your problem is taken as an example in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: That's what I thought too but no matter how small $a$ is, $x \to \infty$ so it would carry $|ax|$ out of $(-1,1)$. Besides, how would one explain that it works for small $m$ better than for large?

Comment: It's not ClaudeLeibovici but JeanMarie who has answered. Indeed, the issue is less "simple" than I thought at first...

Comment: @JeanMarie: there was Claude's comment as well and while I was typing my response, he deleted it and you commented. Thank you for the link, it looks promising.

Comment: I deleted my comment because it was not in line with the question.